# Error from FreeRadius3: No dictionary definition for EAP method md5

Tags: freeradius

I installed freeradius3 from source and run "radiusd -X", then got an error message ：

> /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap[17]: No dictionary definition for EAP method md5
>   /usr/local/etc/raddb/mods-enabled/eap[17]: Instantiation failed for module "eap"

the eap configuration is the same as [freeradius wiki](http://wiki.freeradius.org/modules/Rlm_eap#How-can-I-enable-EAP-MD5-authentication?)

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the v2 /usr/local/share/freeradius and re-installed freeradius v3. It seems like v3 dictionary files are different from the earlier versions.

Comment: We make no attempt to maintain dictionary compatibility between major version releases.